# Spring 3 Security and Relative Redirect URLs

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, squid

We have a Spring 3 app with Spring Security behind a Squid proxy. The issue is that Spring only knows about the internal squid url so after a successful login at `example.com/login` instead of redirecting to `example.com/home` it redirects to `internal.example.com`.

Does anyone know how to deal with this situation?

My Config:

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS') or hasRole('ROLE_GENERAL_ADMINISTRATION')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_GENERAL_ADMINISTRATION')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**" filters="none"/>
    <security:logout invalidate-session="true" logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/"/>
    <security:form-login login-page="/" default-target-url="/dashboard"/>
    <security:anonymous/>
</security:http>
```

#### Edit:

In my case the admins had set up mod_jk incorrectly so everything was fine with squid and the above config.

Comment: I have the same problem with redirects in general, not just security...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having web application with Spring security behind Apache HTTP Reverse proxy and some stupid application which behaves like you described above and the solution for us was to use 
mod_rewrite module

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Anyway what are you saying is very weird because the correct Spring security configuration should use relative urls and it should not matter weather, internal or external host is used in url.

if you configure URL

```
 <security:form-login login-page="//login.jsp" login-processing-url="/login" always-use-default-target="true"/>
```

Should behave the same way in internal or external URL, it sounds like problem in configuration.

Comment: The issue is that `example.com` is actually a proxy (squid) to `internal.example.com`. The spring app is deployed to `internal.example.com`. It's the only url it knows about. But users would/should only see `example.com` and not `internal.example.com`

Comment: Could you please post Spring Security configuration? but it realy looks like the Squid configuration problem.

Comment: Added my config. However, the admins had the jkMount setup incorrectly and that was the issue. You were right, Spring Sec was handling everything as it should.

Comment: @john can u provide those details, because im also struck with this problem

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem, with a nginx reverse proxy in front of my (currently PHP) apps, but others recommend that the work of fixing URLs is done on the proxy, e.g. http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=169534:

> **Response header remapping**. The response headers may contain
>   information that explicitly points to the content web server. One
>   example is the "Location:" header that is used with redirections. The
>   reverse proxy servers remap the "Location:" field, replacing the
>   reference to the content web server with its own address.

Also an answer on a related question: ["Redirect to https for few services using spring"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13519396/2495717).