# Redirect to https for few services using spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have an application which uses spring (also spring security) where few services were kept outside the secured resource set by specifying like below in the applicationContext.xml:

```
<http pattern="/services/rest/nohisb/Msgs" security="none"/>
```

Now these services needs to be accessed only via https. Container is configured to have https. Requirement is when user access the above service on http, he should be redirected to https (port number too changes, as it in not the default 443).

Is it possible to achieve this via spring ?

thanks

Nohsib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to achieve using [Spring Channel Processing](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/access/channel/ChannelProcessingFilter.html) and [PortMapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/PortMapperImpl.html)

Spring Channel Processing used to define http/https access URL Patterns. For Example-

Https Access URL-

```
https://localhost/myapp/user/myaccount
```

Http: Access URL-

```
http://localhost/myapp/home
```

Then if user access the secure URL in http mode "**http://localhost/myapp/user/myaccount**" spring channel security redirect the user to secure URL "**https://localhost/myapp/user/myaccount**" and vice verse.

PortMapper Bean is used map non-standard port numbers for HTTP and HTTPS mapping

**Sample Configuration:**

***Channel Processing Bean Definition And Port Mapper-***

```
<bean id="channelProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelProcessingFilter">
  <property name="channelDecisionManager" ref="channelDecisionManager"/>
  <property name="securityMetadataSource">
        <security:filter-security-metadata-source path-type="ant">
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/services/rest/nohisb/Msgs**" access="REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL" />
            <security:intercept-url pattern="/**/*.html**" access="REQUIRES_SECURE_CHANNEL" />

            <!-- more pattern definition -->

        </security:filter-security-metadata-source>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="channelDecisionManager" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.ChannelDecisionManagerImpl">
  <property name="channelProcessors">
    <list>
        <ref bean="secureChannelProcessor"/>
        <ref bean="insecureChannelProcessor"/>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

<bean id="secureChannelProcessor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.SecureChannelProcessor">
    <property name="entryPoint" ref="secureEntryPoint"/>
</bean>

<bean id="insecureChannelProcessor" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.InsecureChannelProcessor">
    <property name="entryPoint" ref="insecureEntryPoint"/>
</bean>

<bean id="secureEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.RetryWithHttpsEntryPoint">
    <property name="portMapper" ref="portMapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="insecureEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.channel.RetryWithHttpEntryPoint">
    <property name="portMapper" ref="portMapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="portMapper" class="org.springframework.security.web.PortMapperImpl">
    <property name="portMappings">
        <map>
            <entry key="80" value="443"/>
            <entry key="8081" value="8443"/>
            <entry key="8443" value="8081"/>
            <!-- so on... -->
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

***Filter Mapping-***

```
<security:http auto-config="false" 
            entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint" 
            access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" >

    <security:custom-filter position="CHANNEL_FILTER" ref="channelProcessingFilter"/>

    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.html*" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,admin,user"  />
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/*.jsp" access="ROLE_ANONYMOUS,admin,user" />

    <!-- more pattern definition -->

</security:http>
```

Comment: @Nohsib - added details of channel processing, please have a look and let me know

Comment: @ jeevatkm : Getting an exception --> No bean named 'authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint' is defined

Comment: @Nohsib - it seems your spring security implementation doesn't have authentication entry point. please remove this bean mapping `entry-point-ref="authenticationProcessingFilterEntryPoint"` and try again.  If you're still facing issue, then please share your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can write Servlet filter that will check request scheme and URL and sent redirect when needed.
But actually such stuff should be done not in the java code, but in a reverse proxy or balancer. Usually servlet container is used behind proxy (nginx?) or apache (mod_proxy) That's the place to configure https/http redirecting etc.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be simpler to use the Spring Security namespace configuration as described in http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-requires-channel to define port mappings?